# Angular 10: How to highlight element on navbar depending on scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, angular

I am making a single page in Angular 10. It a simple page and I would like to highlight navbar depending on scroll. how can i highlight the element on navbar where i am currently, but make sure it is single page , so i am navigation to sections with id in my page.
here is my code:

HOME.COMPONENT.html**strong text**

`

```
    <!-- site header
    ================================================== -->
    <header id="navbar" class="s-header" (Scroll)="onWindowScroll($event);">
        <nav class="header-nav-wrap">
            <ul class="header-main-nav">
                <li><a class="smoothscroll" href='/home' title="intro">Intro</a></li>
                <li><a class="smoothscroll" href='home#about' title="about">About</a></li>
                <li><a class="smoothscroll" href='home#services' title="services">Services</a></li>
                <li><a class="smoothscroll" href='home#works' title="works">Works</a></li>
                <li><a class="smoothscroll" href='home#contact-us' title="contact us">Say Hello</a></li>    
            </ul>
        </nav>

    </header> <!-- end s-header -->
     
     <!-- intro
    ================================================== -->
    <section id="intro" class="s-intro target-section">

        <div class="row intro-content">

            <div class="column large-9 mob-full intro-text">
                <h3>Hello, I'm xyz</h3>
                <h1>
                    Full stack Developer <br>
                    and Dotnet Developer <br>
                    Based In somewhere.
                </h1>
            </div>

            <div class="intro-grid"></div>
            <div class="intro-pic" style="background-image: url(/assets/images/intro-pic.jpg);"></div>

        </div> <!-- end row -->

    </section> <!-- end intro -->

    <section id="about" class="s-about">
        hi about
    </section>
<section id="services" class="s-services">
        hi services
    </section>
<section id="works" class="s-works">
        hi works
    </section>
<section id="contact-us" class="s-contactUs">
        hi contacts
    </section>`
```

**HOME.COMPONENT.ts**

```
    import { Component, OnInit, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import $ from 'jquery';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  /* sticky navbar on Scrolldown
    * ------------------------------------------------------ */

  @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
  onWindowScroll(e) {
     if (window.pageYOffset > 200) {
       let element = document.getElementById('navbar');
       element.classList.add('sticky');
     } else {
      let element = document.getElementById('navbar');
        element.classList.remove('sticky'); 
     }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a flag on the component and use it to set the class

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  menuSticky = false;

  @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
  onWindowScroll(e) {
    if (window.pageYOffset > 200) {
      this.menuSticky = true;
    } else {
      this.menuSticky = false; 
    }
  }
}
```

and use it in the template

```
<header id="navbar" class="s-header" [ngClass]="{ sticky: menuSticky }" (Scroll)="onWindowScroll($event);">
```